# load data from database instead of array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using a jQuery plugin [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) to autocomplete the tags in the form input field. The plugin loads the available tags stored in an array.

```
$("#mytags").tagit({
    availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]
});
```

I copied following function from the plugin's javascript code, I believe it is main function to load tags:

```
tag_input.autocomplete({
            source: options.availableTags, 
            select: function(event,ui){
                if (is_new (ui.item.value)) {
                    create_choice (ui.item.value);
                }
                // Cleaning the input.
                tag_input.val("");

                // Preventing the tag input to be update with the chosen value.
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The plugin works fine and autocomplete the tags from the availableTags array, however I would like to make a small change in it.
Instead of loading the tags from the array, I would like to load tags from mySQL database table. The table has following structure:

tags:

```
tag_id      tag_name
1            c++
2            java
3            php
4            javascript
5            ruby
```

So How can I autoload the tag names from the database (using PHP) instead of loading from the above array? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. Re-word **this** question if you feel you're not getting your point across. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can like:

Instead of

```
source: options.availableTags
```

use this:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    var term = request.term // This will hold the text you typed in autocomplete
    $.get(url, data, function(data){
        // Build an array to return
        var dataToReturn = [];
    });
    response(dataToReturn);
}
```

Comment: thanks dude. Could you please give an example of PHP code to, and also this about the variable url, you used in get function.

Comment: Here's a working example [http://jsfiddle.net/enqQW/](http://jsfiddle.net/enqQW/). I am not a php guy, so sorry cannot help. This example is not from remote source but can be converted easily. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I get the following `dataToReturn is not defined
[Break On This Error] response(dataToReturn);  `

Comment: Did you see my jsFiddle code. Its not related to dataToReturn.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin seems to be based on `jQuery UI Autocomplete`, so the source parameter in your code may be either an array, a string or a callback. Please refer to

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

for the appropriate documentation. Basically, you can put in a string with a url to your serving script, which parses the `$_GET['term']` assigned by the plugin and returns an array of your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to dynamically build up the -

```
$("#mytags").tagit({
    availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]
});
```

JavaScript code. This [blog entry](http://www.designcodeexecute.com/2008/02/08/create-javascript-array-with-php-mysql/) contains a function that should be roughly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example for using a [remote datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote). The `source` parameter is the name of a php script which is doing a MySQL query and returning the data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with the following code:

```
$('#tags').tagit({
    tagSource: function(request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        $.get("/suggestTags?term=" + term, function(data){
            var dataToReturn = data;
            response(dataToReturn); 
        });
    }
});
```